# Triggering JS function from C# using SignalR with Clients.All.myJsfunction

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr

So, here is my issue:

I might be doing something wrong but what I basically trying is, connecting two peers with a video chat while making text conversation.

Here's my ChatHub.cs

```
public void Send(string name, string message)
{
    // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
    Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
}
```

JS part of it

```
chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) { //my function does its job }
```

This works very well but for video call in ChatHub.cs some function in ChatHub calls

```
public void GetConnectionIDandSet()
{
    var users = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ConnectedUsers);
    Clients.All.getConnectionIDandSet(users);
}
```

and corresponding JS part of it

```
chat.client.getConnectionIDandSet = function (users) { // do the job }
```

and when i try to debug it on console

`Clients.All.getConnectionIDandSet(users); does not trigger`

`chat.client.getConnectionIDandSet = function (users) { // do the job }`

So, what am I doing wrong at here?

The gist for full project is [here](https://minilink.net/XDqcgy8).

Comment: The code here and the code on GitHub does not much. I tried to understand on GitHub but i didn't found "getConnectionIDandSet"...

Comment: Mistake 1:  (According code on GitHub): You must set querystring bevor you start the connection. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client. Additional hint: For readabily of your code I suggest you to define all methods which the server can call on the client bevor your start the connection

Comment: woah @Stephu was not aware of that learned someting new today now it triggers the function but having problems to catch the answer need to work a bit more i guess btw if you put your answer as a comment i wold gladly check it as a solution

Comment: Your welcome. What was the point which helps you? Querystring? Or the otherone. In the case of query string please modify your question that other users see what you did wrong. Otherwise the answer makes no sens for the others.

Comment: i moved the querystring functions before the call and they worked in the right way @Stephu now lookig for the problem of creating or getting answer digging back on debugger i guess and any suggestins how to modify the question?

Comment: Show some code with: 1. one method which the client can call on the server, 2. code where you start the connection 3. code where you add the querrystring. (We should see that you did adding the query string the wrong way.

Comment: For additional problem please create new question, We will help you there also:)

Comment: if i cant find the solution myself i will ask it :) but cant trust on you geniuses all the time @Stephu must dig in myself and search for solution to learn more and will edit the question after the working hours end ty for saving the day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mistake:**

(According code on GitHub): You must set querystring bevor you start the connection. See: learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/….

**Additional hint:**

For readabily of your code I suggest you to define all methods which the server can call on the client bevor your start the connection